# Reading a file using fgetc() but characters are skipped

Tags: c, esp-idf

Reading a file using fgetc() but characters are skipped. Only when I use fseek() to to move the cursor one step back then it works fine. My issue is I cannot for the life of me wrap my head around it why do I need to use fseek() to solve the problem. I need fresh eyes to explain since my brain is in a lock state.

Code below skips a character

```
int file_chars = 0;
size_t hdr_size = 15;
char hdr_cook_val[hdr_size];
esp_err_t get_cookie = httpd_req_get_cookie_val(req,COOKIE_NAME,hdr_cook_val,&hdr_size);
if(get_cookie == ESP_ERR_NOT_FOUND && req->uri[0] == '/' && req->method == HTTP_GET){
     FILE *index_file = fopen(HTML_PART_FOLDER"/index.txt","r");
     char *hdr_val = malloc(sizeof(char)*MALLOC_DEFAULT_SIZE);
     if(hdr_val==NULL){ESP_LOGE(TAG,"Malloc failed variable name: hdr_val");return ESP_OK;}
     for(int i=0;;i++){
         file_chars = fgetc(index_file);
         if(file_chars==EOF){
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,hdr_val,i);
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,NULL,0);
             break;
         }
         hdr_val[i] = file_chars;
         if(i==9999){
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,hdr_val,i);
             i=-1;
             vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(20));
         }
     }
     free(hdr_val);
     fclose(index_file);
     return ESP_OK;
}
```

using the same code but only adding the line `fseek(index_file,ftell(index_file)-1,SEEK_SET);` all is good

```
int file_chars = 0;
size_t hdr_size = 15;
char hdr_cook_val[hdr_size];
esp_err_t get_cookie = httpd_req_get_cookie_val(req,COOKIE_NAME,hdr_cook_val,&hdr_size);
if(get_cookie == ESP_ERR_NOT_FOUND && req->uri[0] == '/' && req->method == HTTP_GET){
     FILE *index_file = fopen(HTML_PART_FOLDER"/index.txt","r");
     char *hdr_val = malloc(sizeof(char)*MALLOC_DEFAULT_SIZE);
     if(hdr_val==NULL){ESP_LOGE(TAG,"Malloc failed variable name: hdr_val");return ESP_OK;}
     for(int i=0;;i++){
         file_chars = fgetc(index_file);
         if(file_chars==EOF){
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,hdr_val,i);
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,NULL,0);
             break;
         }
         hdr_val[i] = file_chars;
         if(i==9999){
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,hdr_val,i);
             fseek(index_file,ftell(index_file)-1,SEEK_SET);
             i=-1;
             vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(20));
         }
     }
     free(hdr_val);
     fclose(index_file);
     return ESP_OK;
}
```

Comment: Did you consider compiling your application with [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) -it has cross-compilers- invoked as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then using the [GDB](https://www.sourceware.org/gdb/) debugger? (GDB can do remote debugging)

Comment: BTW, unrelated: `sizeof (char)` is `1` by definition. You don't need to multiply by `1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code loads until the 10,000th character, then only sends 9999 of them.

Try this:

```
     int i = 0;
     for( ;; ) {
         file_chars = fgetc(index_file);
         if( file_chars == EOF ) {
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,hdr_val,i);
             httpd_resp_send_chunk(req,NULL,0);
             break;
         }
         hdr_val[ i ] = file_chars;
         // count that character and test for complete batch
         if( ++i == 10000 ) {
             httpd_resp_send_chunk( req, hdr_val, i ); // Send 10000 per batch
             i = 0;
             vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(20));
         }
     }
```

And, learn to use the spacebar... Dense code is both difficult to read and provides shelter for bugs.

**EDIT:**
On reflection, if the source file is an exact multiple of 10000, the code above will send **two** empty 'chunks'. This is not good! The following is more compact while fixing that problem. PLUS, `10000` is a *magic number* that should be identified somehow.

```
#define BYTES_PER_OUT_CHUNK  10000 // why 10000? Why not...

    int i = 0;
    while( ( file_chars = fgetc( index_file ) ) != EOF ) {
        hdr_val[ i++ ] = file_chars;
        if( i == BYTES_PER_OUT_CHUNK ) {
            httpd_resp_send_chunk( req, hdr_val, i );
            i = 0;
            vTaskDelay( pdMS_TO_TICKS( 20 ) );
        }
    }
    if( i )
        httpd_resp_send_chunk( req, hdr_val, i );
    httpd_resp_send_chunk( req, NULL, 0 );
```

Comment: reading the file in chunks of 10000 (using malloc) to send a web page to the user since chunk encoding is supported by the http server. Your solution is more compact, efficient and works great thank you.

Comment: Glad to be of service! `:-)` Cheers!

Comment: That last chunk of data sent might be 9990 bytes... I don't know... Should there be a delay before the "null" chunk is pushed at the output channel???

Comment: i dont think its necessary the delay is there only for the freertos task not to trigger the watchdog and hold a task for too long.